# Run a .Net MVC5 application on Mono

Tags: linux, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am developing an .Net 4.5.1 MVC5 application in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows.

Now I want to know, if it is possible to run this application on Linux ( Ubuntu 12.04 )?
Would it be possible to use OWIN?

Comment: Have you tried running on Linux? Your question will get more traction if you have specific issues.

Answer (score 4):

Owin can be run self hosted which means no IIS which is a start see here

[Use OWIN to Self-Host ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api)

Then to also help see this post about deploying to a mono instance on heroku

[Running OWIN/Katana apps on Heroku](http://friism.com/running-owin-katana-apps-on-heroku)