# When is the mono implementation of mvc 5 expected to come out ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I am trying to figure out the architecture for a product revamp. The current project is in Asp.Net Webforms 4.0 but I am leaning heavily towards MVC 5 now. Problem is that a few customers (around 10%) do not want to get stuck with Windows Server licensing but our dev team/environment is .Net/Windows based. I was wondering if I could build it in MVC 5 leveraging the latest features like scaffolding, filtering, etc and also be able to port it to Linux based platform through Mono.

Does it sound realistic ?

I wanted to know about the timelines for a stable implementation of MVC 5 in Mono so that I can know whether I can depend on Mono when my team would be working on portability 2-4 months down the line. Otherwise MVC 5 may be a dealbraker for us.

I went through the Mono site and it links to StackOverflow for any questions ... so here I am

Comment: Found a few links similar in nature but not clear [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455600/run-a-net-mvc5-application-on-mono
[link]http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/NET-4-5-1-MVC-5-td4661331.html
[link]http://curtis.schlak.com/2014/02/04/setup-asp-net-mvc-4-on-monodevelop-4.2.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC 5 will likely never be 100% stable/supported on Mono, as it builds upon System.Web <s>which Microsoft never open-sourced and is difficult to recreate in Mono.</s> *edit* this may change now that the sources for System.Web have been made open source.

MVC 6 (and all the other stuff from ASP.NET "vNext") is a complete rewrite to get rid of System.Web and will support Mono out of the box, as Microsoft actively tests on it.

See http://www.asp.net/vnext, https://github.com/aspnet/Home and https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc.

My advice would be to keep an eye an ASP.NET "vNext" (it is in development stage right now, but will be the future of ASP.NET for the next decade) if you want to have proper Mono support. You can also start with MVC 5 now, but be aware that there **will** be breaking changes by the time you upgrade to MVC6.

Comment: so i guess question is when is asp mvc 6 coming out

Comment: They are developing ASP.NET vNext in the open, so you can follow the team's progress in the GitHub repositories, try out daily builds or watch the community standup meetings: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF. As said, it's currently in development and from what I've heard will be released in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [Nancyfx](http://nancyfx.org/), which is a MVC framework that has been built from the start to work with .net and mono.

I currently use it on a project. I develop on windows and .net and then publish(copy files) to Unbuntu and mono. Its very seamless.

Nancy's hosting support is very broad also.

1. [Hosting Nancy with ASP.NET](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-asp.net)
2. [Hosting Nancy with WCF](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-wcf)
3. [Hosting Nancy with Azure](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-azure)
4. [Hosting Nancy with OWIN](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin)
5. [Hosting Nancy with Umbraco](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-Umbraco)
6. [Hosting Nancy with Nginx on Ubuntu](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-Nginx-on-Ubuntu)
7. [Hosting Nancy with FastCgi](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-FastCgi)
8. [Self Hosting Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Self-Hosting-Nancy)

Comment: how does it compare with asp mvc webapi ef signalr stack

Comment: Nancy supports [Content Negotiation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content-Negotiation) which lets you use the same endpoint for views and api request. Here is a SignalR example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691826/signalr-plus-nancyfx-a-simple-but-well-worked-example